# Can effects/after effects of someone's fruit power's be neutralised by sea/sea water?

Tags: one-piece

Can effects of someone's devil fruits like Soru-Soru(i.e. Soul-Soul of Big mom), Hobi-Hobi (Sugar), Op-Op (Law) etc. that have long lasting effects on others neutralised from sea/sea water ?

like if -

1. Big mom's homies drown. or,
2. Sugar's toys drown. or,
3. Law's patients with heart taken out drown or are attacked by sea water/sea stone.

P.S. when I say drown I also mean attacked by sea water / sea prism stone.

Comment: To address the second part of your questions regarding salt. `Devil Fruit users are susceptible to all types of water, not just seawater. This includes the white sea surrounding Skypiea. [Oda] elaborated on this, saying that "moving" water, like rain or waves, does not weaken Devil Fruit users, while standing water does.` - [Wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Devil_Fruit#Side_Effects_of_Devil_Fruits)

Comment: The question title and description are two different things. Salt is specifically mentioned as a counter only to [Kage Kage no Mi](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Kage_Kage_no_Mi#Trivia) as a reference to purifying evil spirits. Sea water contains salt too, which is why that also worked on the zombies. The only equivalent to sea water seems to be sea-prism stone, not salt.

Haven't posted as an answer because I too am curious about the original question regarding sea water and law's power. I don't think we have much evidence on any other fruit effects being countered, just the users.

Comment: Basically, this question asks if the Toy Soldier would have been able to turn back to normality just by been submerged in "sea" water around Dressrosa, and then make forcefully make the other toys (who probably could not do that voluntary because of the contract) do the same. Hopefully that is not a thing, otherwise the whole arc becomes VERY stupid - Sugar power suddenly becomes far less of a problem, but I admit I also had this idea before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently all this comes from a series of misconceptions.

First, the effects water has on Devil Fruit users does not come from "salt", nor by the "water" itself (as a mere liquid). "Salt" is a specific weakness tied to Moria (in popular culture salt has a purify effect on demons and undead, see for example the common "a circle of salt can be used to protect you from a demon"), while Crocodile is weak to any form of "water", including rain or water someone could spray on him (and that is WHY he worked so hard to be sure it would never rain).

The specific weakness Devil Fruit have is not just "water". It is what Oda called "standing" water.

> D: Odacchi! Here's a question for you! Crocodile can't fight water because he's "sand," right? Then how does he bathe?! Does he at all?! That's filthy!! Do you bathe, Odacchi? by Crocodile's Mother
>
> O: First of all, let's discuss the problem of Devil Fruit users bathing themselves. People who have eaten a Devil Fruit are "hated" by the sea, and cannot swim. The "sea" here can refer to anything from rivers, pools and baths to any kind of ***standing water***. On a worldwide level, they are all the "sea." When these people enter the water, ***not only can they not use their powers, they have trouble moving their bodies at all***. They might be able to struggle a bit, but it wouldn't do much good. That's if their entire bodies are submerged in the "sea." With less than half the body or just the limbs, it gets easier. Also, rain and ***dripping water have no effect at all***. Therefore, hip baths or showers are the most common choice. Now, in Crocodile's case, "water" is the weakness of his very powers, so his abilities are robbed even in the shower. But it's not like there are enemies around when you take a shower, so I'd bet he would take them even with his powers being blocked. Don't you think? ---And to answer your final question, about myself bathing. As it happens, I do bathe. Twice! In a year!

So, basically, the weakness to the "standing water" is caused by the fact that "standing water" is considered part of the "sea", and the ***will*** of the sea "hates" the Devil Fruit users. Coincidentally, the water also contains ---midiclorian--- Pyrobloin so Sea Prism Stone (which is made from Pyrobloin) still somehow carries the will of the sea.

It is also important to notice that based on Oda's answer, the sea hates the Devil Fruit user, not simply their power. Therefore the effect of the fruit is on the ***user***, not on their power.

The difference could seem very subtle but there are enough evidences in the manga to prove that "standing water" actually works by making the victim weak to a point they can't no longer use their power ***willing***. This does not mean that the powers are negated in any way, so any "permanent" effect that does not require active sustain will continue to exist.

Let's see some examples that should prove this.

### Case #1: Arlong Park

[image: Luffy body has still rubber like properties while underwater]

Luffy falls in the water and while this is enough to make him basically faint Genzo and Nojiko are still able to save him by *forcefully* stretching his neck. So, while Luffy was rendered too weak to even move by the water his body kept all his "rubber like" properties even when submerged.

### Case 2: Water Luffy

[image]

Luffy was able to use "moving" water without any effect during his fights with Crocodile. Crocodile was instead affected since his fruit is *specifically* weak to *any form of water*.

### Case 3: any bath scene with a Devil Fruit user

[image]

If we compare different scenes involving fruit users it becomes quite evident that the effects scale with how much of the body is actually submerged. In the picture above Luffy and Brook are weakened since about half their body is submerged, but they don't seem to feel any effect nor does Yamato in the Wano ending onsen scene (where they are standing in the water and only their feet are submerged - see it [here - warning: very fanservice and also contains spoilers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/As3gU.jpg) ). Another blatant example is the old artwork with Nami and Robin in an onsen with the three monkeys.

### Case 4: Luffy underwater fight

[image]

Luffy body wasn't actually touching the water so he was not weakened. Notice that this scene will also prove something else soon afterward.

### Case 5: Zushi Zushi affecting a Marine battle ship ##[image]

Fujitora's powers were shown to be able to make a Marine's battle ship levitate. Remember: the hull of most Marine's ships is made from Sea Primstone, so it is very possible that in this scene Fujitora powers were affecting Primstone too. If this is not enough please refer to point six.

### Case 6: Law swapping  Sea Primstone shackles and cutting them

[image]

In this scene Law is able to remove his shackles because he actually swapped the Seastone ones with regular ones before. While one could claim that he didn't use his power to do so the fact he says "so I can swap them **at any time**" seems to clearly point in that direction.

### Case 7: Mr 3 key and the Primstone shackles

[image]
The key Mr 3 created is clearly a product of his power. Yet said key was used to open a Primstone shackle and did NOT dissipate when touching it. This is similar to Aokiji being able to actually turn sea water into ice.

### Case 8: Smoker's Sea Prism sword

[image]
With enough training and will, a Devil Fruit user can resist the effect of moving water.

### Case 9: chained Big Mom

[image]
Apparently Big Mom chains were made from Sea Prism Stone, yet she didn't seem very effected by that.

### Case 10: imprisoned Smoker and Tashigi

[image]
At that time Tashigi and Smoker were under the swapping effect of Law's fruit. The effect was not negated when they came in contact with the Sea Prism stone chains.

---

Now we can draw some conclusions from all this examples (notice: anytime water is mentioned we are actually referring to moving water or Sea Prism stone unless otherwise noticed):

- Passive "always on" effects are NOT nullified if the user comes in contact with water.
- Only standing water counts, rain or any form of moving water has no effect.
- The effect scale with how much of your body is submerged.
- The effect only comes from direct contact with the water.
- Devil Fruit users powers can actually affect Primstone and water.
- Any product of a Devil Fruit power can touch water with no effect, it is only the user that is effected.
- The will of the user can negate the effect of the will of the sea
- when under the effect of moving water a Devil Fruit user won't be able to create any new effect but **PERMANENT** effects already in place aren't negated

To summarize this in one simple line: moving water does not act on the Fruit powers. It acts by making the user weak to the point they can no longer sustain new effect of their powers (or any effect that requires constant application).

Therefore we can conclude that in most cases the effect of a Devil Fruit user power are NOT negated by contact with moving water. So, anyone turned in a toy by Sugar can't simply be tossed in the water to revert the transformation.

The effect of a fruit can be permanent (example: Luffy's rubber like body) or sustained (Sugar's power). There is no clear rule on whether a power is permanent or sustained but the difference should be clear: if a "permanent" power user is disabled (killed, fainted, submerged in water) the effects of his power stay while in the case of "sustained" power the effect dissipate.

Based on her claims, Boa petrification power is a permament effect: after you are turned to stone you would remain in that state even if she faints or is killed (or if she bathes, would be fun if Margaret simply had to wait next time Boa went to her bath pool). Sugar power instead is sustained and that is why making her faint is sufficient to make any toy turn back to their original self. Another sustained power is for example Vander Decken's (as soon as he faints the ship falls).

Notice that the distinction is not always intuitive: there is no reason Boa petrification should be permanent while Sugar power isn't. Zoan powers are also "permanent" since while moving water neutralizes the user strength they remain in whatever form they were at the moment (Chopper does NOT turn in a regular reindeer when he falls in the sea in multiple chapters, but his strength is neutralized to the point he can't no longer sustain Monster Point).

There is also another Odd-Ball worth mentioning:

[image]

For some weird reason Gild Tesoro creations are actually vulnerable to water. He shares Crocodile weakness but in his case there doesn't seem to be a "logical" reasoning behind this (like "water pokemon beats sand").

It is also worth noticing that all the evidence so far collected open a different question...

When Luffy falls in Boa's bath she is surprised that he didn't turn into stone. But she is submerged in water , so she should not be able to use her power at that time.
This can be explained if we assume that her power is not an active power she has to use directly (like Sugar's) but instead a permanent state of her "body". This should also explain why her power has permanent effects while Sugar's one can be nullified if she faints.